# Moving Docker Wordpress site to AWS EC2: Error establishing a database connection

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose

Before moving my Wordpress site to AWS EC2, I have self-hosted it with no issues. After downloading `docker` and `docker-compose` to migrate the Wordpress site over, I have now hit the "Error establishing a database connection" roadblock when accessing it via http://ec2-public-ip:8081. I have checked through all the environment variables in my `docker-compose` file and making sure that the environment variables tally with the `wp-config.php` file.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  # Database
  db:
    platform: linux/x86_64
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
    networks:
      - wpsite

  # Wordpress
  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '8081:80'
    volumes: ['./:/var/www/html']
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: password
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
    networks:
      - wpsite

# php
  phpmyadmin:
    depends_on:
      - db
    platform: linux/x86_64
    image: phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '8082:80'
    environment:
      PMA_HOSTS: db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
    networks:
      - wpsite

secrets:
  sql_root_password:
    file: ./sql_root_password.txt

networks:
  wpsite:
volumes:
  db_data:
```

wp-config.php

```
...
// ** Database settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define( 'DB_NAME', getenv_docker('WORDPRESS_DB_NAME', 'wordpress') );

/** Database username */
define( 'DB_USER', getenv_docker('WORDPRESS_DB_USER', 'wordpress') );

/** Database password */
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', getenv_docker('WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD', 'password') );

/**
 * Docker image fallback values above are sourced from the official WordPress installation wizard:
 * https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/1356f6537220ffdc32b9dad2a6cdbe2d010b7a88/wp-admin/setup-config.php#L224-L238
 * (However, using "example username" and "example password" in your database is strongly discouraged.  Please use strong, random credentials!)
 */

/** Database hostname */
define( 'DB_HOST', getenv_docker('WORDPRESS_DB_HOST', 'mysql') );

/** Database charset to use in creating database tables. */
define( 'DB_CHARSET', getenv_docker('WORDPRESS_DB_CHARSET', 'utf8') );

/** The database collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define( 'DB_COLLATE', getenv_docker('WORDPRESS_DB_COLLATE', '') );
...
```

This issue also seems to have an impact on my phpMyAdmin installation accessed via http://ec2-public-ip:8082. Even though I can connect to the login page, I cannot login using the appropriate (i.e. my MySQL) credentials.

I have also made sure to run `sudo docker-compose down` after each modification to my configuration just to ensure that the containers are rebuilt properly. To be on the safe side, I have also opened up all the necessary ports (and perhaps unnecessary ones) for the security group associated to this EC2 instance hosting my Wordpress container.

[Screenshot of security group configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0YpC.png)

Answer (score 0):

This error is related to mysql connection from your ec2 and not related to wordpress.

Perform these checks:

### telnet

`telnet <rds_mysql_host_here> 3306`

You should see something like

[image]

If there is not telnet response, change the security settings of your rds mysql instance

### mysql client

You could use docker to start a mysql container 5 or 8 dependig of your requirements

```
docker run -it --name mysql-5 --entrypoint bash  mysql:5.7.44
docker run -it --name mysql-8 --entrypoint bash  mysql:8.2.0
```

Then, inside connect to your rds :

```
mysql -u admin -h <rds_mysql_host_here> -p
```

You should connect it using the root or wordpress user created in your mysql. Finally perform some query to your tables:

```
show databases;
use acme_db;
show tables;
select * from foo;
```

If you can establish the connection , change the security settings of your rds mysql instance

Comment: I should have done a better job with my screenshot; even though I left the ec2-rds connection in the security group, I'm actually trying to connect to the mySQL DB as per my `docker-compose.yml` file and not the RDS instance. Will the `db` service IP address be the same as that of my ec2 instance public IP?

Comment: Found the issue! I downloaded Apache when I started the container so that I could pass the EC2 health checks. It seems that the Apache installation messed with the Docker Wordpress container (which also contains an Apache installation).

Comment: That is not related to our mysql error