# connecting spring boot app to AWS RDS failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I have a weird situation I'm trying to figure out for a few days
I have an AWS RDS (mySQL) service running on port 3306 the SG assigned allows all traffic from everywhere.

Spring boot is supposed to be connected to that RDS. When I run the spring boot locally on my machine it does get connected to the RDS. everything is yay! :) After deploying the spring app to EC2 and compiling the jar file with the same Java JRE I have on my PC
it cannot establish a connection for some reason.

Inbound rules for Ec2 are all traffic allowed from everywhere in and out. Both Ec2 and RDS are on the same VPC

Also I will mention that connecting though the CLI in EC2 to RDS works fine. Tried to open all the traffic in all services as I though it is a problem related to SG

after trying telnet mysqlIP 3306

I got:

[image: photo]

Comment: Perform these validations in the ec2: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77692364/3957754 and share us the details in the question

Comment: thanks for the response, I've updated the post with the command validation

Comment: Try with the mysql client and share us the details. Also share us your application.properties or yaml. Also to replicate your issue you can create a [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and share it in github. Take care your credentials. Use env variables